# Initializing a matrix

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, element

I wrote the following code:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

int vals[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

CvMat mat = cvMat(3,3,CV_8UC1,vals);

for(int i=0;i<mat.rows;i++)
{
    int* ptr = (int*) (mat.data.ptr + i* mat.step);

    for(int j=0;j<mat.cols;j++)
    {
                printf("%d\t",*ptr++);

    }
    printf("\n");
}

return 0;
}
```

The output I got is:

```
1              2               3
512            768             1024
196608         262144          327680
```

The matrix is not initialized properly. The pointer `ptr` points to the beginning of each row and incrementing it gives the element in corresponding column. Is my assumption correct? Is there any mistake with the cvMat constructor used or the access method of elements?

Comment: This is C++ isn't it and not C? They are quite different languages. What is `CvMat`? What is `_Tchar`? Why do you use a cast?

Comment: CvMat is the matrix data structure.                               '_tchar' i just left it as such after creating a new project. (it appears by default). but can you tell me what is the arguments in the main funtion '_tmain' meant for ?? (these things appear by default)

Comment: You still didn't give the context of your question, how are we supposed to guess these things? Please tag your question correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you use the `cv::Mat`class?

It has some handy functions which handle memory better.

for declaring and initializing `cv::Mat` in your case the code will look like this:

```
int main()
{
   int vals[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    Mat mat = cv::Mat(3, 3, CV_8UC1, vals).clone();

    for(int i = 0; i < mat.rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < mat.cols; j++)
        {
             cout << mat.at<uchar>(j,i) << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you ... i have read some tutorials from the internet in which the way of declaring , initializing and accessing were given as i hav used in my code.. can you please give some link to learn about your aforementioned style of programming ... some link that details about your methods of manipulating matrices etc.

Comment: Have a look at [Opencv cheatsheet](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Welcome?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=opencv_cheatsheet.pdf). A lot of functions which are commonly used are explained quite effectly in this cheatsheet which can also be found inside docs folder in your opencv source

Comment: Why do you use cout << mat.at<uchar>(j,i) << " ";? It seems it will initialize the matrix column by column.

Comment: cout call is only made to show the contents of mat in the console window.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong. mat.data.ptr is for unsigned chars
from
http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/opencv-intro.html

```
uchar*  ptr;     // data pointer for an unsigned char matrix
```

you should use

```
mat.data.i
```

for integers

You initialize matrix properly but printing it wrong because of using the wrong pointer of data structure.

```
CvMat                      // 2D array
  |-- int   type;          // elements type (uchar,short,int,float,double) and flags
  |-- int   step;          // full row length in bytes
  |-- int   rows, cols;    // dimensions
  |-- int   height, width; // alternative dimensions reference
  |-- union data;
      |-- uchar*  ptr;     // data pointer for an unsigned char matrix
      |-- short*  s;       // data pointer for a short matrix
      |-- int*    i;       // data pointer for an integer matrix
      |-- float*  fl;      // data pointer for a float matrix
      |-- double* db;      // data pointer for a double matrix
```

See? Did this help?

Comment: You seem to know more about the question than is written there. Could you please contribute to the effort by first improving the question?

Comment: as i said before he declares "ints" (each 4-8 bytes and uses mat.data.i) and using other type pointers . mat.data.ptr(each unsigned char is 1 byte)

Comment: thank you so much ... i get that being declared as an int pointer i hav to use data.i , but can you explain why incrementing integer pointer by 1 is adding 4 to the address??? the size of int is only 2 bytes, so it should be address + 2 . why is it address + 4 ?

Comment: size of int is minimum 4 bytes in 32 bit system

Comment: and most probably an unsigned char is 1 bytes

Comment: whats your system and os spec?

Comment: thank you ,i checked it just now,size of int is 4bytes , also i have another doubt. .. in the CvMat structure step is length of row in bytes, when i print its value i am getting 3, but it should be 3*4bytes = 12bytes since i have 3 integer elements in each row.

Comment: what do you see when you printf(" %i ",sizeof(int));  ? is it 4 ? if yes, then it is 32 bit and equal to your cpu's integer registers size such as eax,ebx,ecx,edx,esi,edi

Comment: hmm then your int size could be 8 bytes. i cant say

Comment: in the CvMat structure step is length of row in bytes, when i print its value i am getting 3, but it should be 3*4bytes = 12bytes since i have 3 integer elements in each row

Comment: ok, when you use sizeof() for array, you get element number. not array size.

Comment: but only if you pass it by value.

Comment: you used sizeof() in a function? and passed array by not reference?

Comment: sorry i couldnt get that... actually it should be 12 right? since 3 integers in a row??  i read from a tutorial that step is length of row in bytes !!

Comment: http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/opencv-intro.html#SECTION00042000000000000000

Comment: this?          int   step  = M->step/sizeof(float);

Comment: i could not understand their accessing method.. just printf("%d",mat.step) gives 3 ... i dont know why? in the link above in matrices and vectors section its given that step - full row length in bytes

Comment: i mean, are you using that printf in the same block where you declare mat.step ?

Comment: Ok, i think i solved this: try a 300x300 matrix and see that it is not 300, it is 600?

Comment: if it uses relative addressing, then it needs only 1 byte if that dimension size is less than 256(i mean the relative-pointer size)

Comment: step is the type size_t which is 1 byte in memory.

Comment: 3 elements: 3 bytes for relative addressing i suspect

Answer (score 0):

There are some strange issues with your code. And unfortunately,  tuğrul büyükışık's answer is only half-correct. Look at these lines:

```
// you reserve 9 integers on the stack (9*4=36bytes)
int vals[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; 

// declare a matrix of uchars. 3*3*1 byte = 9 bytes
// Now, the matrix thinks it has only 9 bytes allocated.
CvMat mat = cvMat(3,3,CV_8UC1,vals); 

// Now you read the values from the matrix. 
// You actually access all the 36 bytes, but if they weren't wrongly allocated 
// at first, you would have a out-of-bounds access. 
for(int i=0;i<mat.rows;i++)
{
    int* ptr = (int*) (mat.data.ptr + i* mat.step);
}
```

**You must convert all your data to the same format**: either int (4 bytes), either uchar (1 byte)

```
int vals[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; 
CvMat mat = cvMat(3,3,CV_32SC1,vals); // 32SC1 means signed integer, 32 bits
```

**OR**

```
unsigned char vals[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
CvMat mat = cvMat(3,3,CV_8UC1,vals); // 8UC1 means unsigned char, 8 bits
```

Comment: yes i understand now...thank you to the core... now i get why previously i got 3 when i printed the value of mat.step (because i used CV_8UC1 the matrix was allocated as 9 bytes one for each element => 3 bytes in a row) , now i used CV_32SC1 it allocates 4bytes to each element => 12 bytes for a row... @tuğrul büyükışık's

Answer (score 0):

Besides the wrong usage (explained by huseyin tugrul buyukisik) your mistake is that you used the wrong type when you created the Matrix

```
int vals[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
CvMat mat = cvMat(3,3,CV_8UC1,vals); // WRONG TYPE!
```

You should use CV_32SC1 (for signed int) when you create the matrix.

Also, when you access the matrix, you should use `mat.ptr<int>(row)`.
Full example:

```
int vals[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

// Fill matrix content without allocating new memory 
// Beware: changing the content of vals changes the content of mat and vice versa
// Use correct type CV_32SC1 or let OpenCV find the correct one by using
// CV_MAKETYPE(cv::DataDepth<int>::value, 1) instead
cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat(3, 3, CV_32SC1, vals);  

// Print content
for(int row = 0; row < mat.rows; row++)
{
    int* rowPtr = mat.ptr<int>(row);

    for(int col = 0; col < mat.cols; col++)
        std::cout << rowPtr[col] << " ";

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```